# Cómo generar Local Notifications que se muestren como Banner en la pantalla de celular

Tags: genexus

Estoy trabajando sobre un objeto Panel SD, que posee un procedure que genera notificaciones locales a través del external object "LocalNotificationInfo" siguiendo lo indicado en la wiki
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?19294,HowTo%3A+Using+LocalNotifications+external+object+in+Smart+Devices

Al probarlo , me generó la notificacion local en forma de icono en el Status Bar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si deslizo hacia abajo (swipe down) se ve la notificacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: Cómo puedo hacer desde Genexus para que la Notificacion Local aparezca en pantalla como una "Banner Notification" (y así llamar la atencion del Usuario, sin esperar a que haga un swipe down)?

Dentro del Emulador fui a:
Ajustes\ Apps & notifications\ Notifications
Y dentro de "Recently Sent" ví la notificacion generada con Genexus a través del "LocalNotificationInfo".
Pero la opcion de "Pop on Screen" aparece desactivada, por eso no aparece como Banner Notification. Cómo se podria generar la Local Notificacion con el "Pop on Screen" activo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por el momento lamentablemente no hay forma de configurar la opción de "Pop on screen" para las Local Notifications. Duda: si la app está cerrada, ¿ahí sí muestra el "banner"?

Comment: Aun debo probar esa parte que mencionas: qué sucede si la app está cerrada; si se dispara la notificacion local y cómo de muestra.